# Restricting access in .NET remoting

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, access-control

- I have a .NET application that uses remoting to expose a singleton object lets say object A.
- This application will run as a service on windows host called host1.
- I want to make sure that only applications running on host1 can access object A.

Is there a way to do this within C# or do I need to configure my firewall accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to write my own custom network sink to block unwanted connections. I did not have to modify the firewall at all